# How to add StencilJS web component dynamically in angular 7 project from .ts file?

Tags: angular, web-component, stenciljs

I want to use a web component generated from stencilJS in my Angular 7 Project. Basically I want to insert a web component into HTML from angular with a typescript file.

I know how to add a component created inside angular to be added dynamically from the Angular 7 project. That is using componentFactory. But How to do same for Web components generated from stencilJS?

```
 @ViewChild('viewContainerRef', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) VCR: ViewContainerRef;

    createComponent() {
        debugger;
        let componentFactory = this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
        let componentRef: ComponentRef<MyComponent> = this.VCR.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (<MyComponent>componentRef.instance).first = 'test1';
        (<MyComponent>componentRef.instance).last = 'test2';

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //this.VCR.TML = '<my-component [first]="first" [last]="last"></my-component>';
        this.createComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Web components are HTML components with some logic, so just using it's tag like any other Angular component should work.

Comment: You didn't mention whether or not you have followed the Angular integration instructions: https://stenciljs.com/docs/angular.